# CGContextSetFillColorWithColor not working with passed in color variable

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to color an image using `CGContextSetFillColorWithColor` and a color variable I'm grabbing from my Parse database.

Changing the color of the image this way works fine:

```
[...]
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"menuButton.png"];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, image.CGImage);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
[...]
```

That changes the menuButton.png to white no problem.

But when I try to change it to the hex color I'm getting from Parse (using a hex color utility) this way:

```
self.bgColor = [post objectForKey:@"bgColor"]; //bgColor = "#ffffff"
[...]
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
   [[UIColor colorWithHexString:self.bgColor] CGColor]);
```

The image no longer appears. Is this a pointer issue? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem and didn't find a direct solution.  The solution for me was to use the `-setFill` method on my `UIColor` object, rather than using the intermediate `CGColor` object:

```
[[UIColor colorWithHexString:self.bgColor] setFill];
```

Comment: Thanks Seamus, unfortunately I'm getting the error `Passing void to parameter of incompatible type CGColorRef (aka struct CGColor *)` when I try that.

Comment: Are you sure that your `-colorWithHexString` call is returning a valid UIColor object?